# Generically retrieving different numeric data types from byte array

Tags: c#, generics

I have a data array of bytes, however this array can hold any unsigned number (byte/ushort/uint/ulong) as bytes.

The problem with this is retrieving the data again into the required type: I want the responsibility of converting the data back to the required datatype in the handler class, and not the one requesting the data again (which could convert a returned byte array representing the value).

Furthermore, ref or out variables, though is one solution, are a hassle as members I'm assigning are not necessarily of the type I'm returning (read explicit enums):

```
public enum SomeEnum : ulong
{ 
// ...
}
```

The functions I have at the moment are:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get data (byte)
/// </summary>
public byte GetDataByte(byte dataIndex)
{
  return this.Data[dataIndex];
}

/// <summary>
/// Get data (ushort)
/// </summary>
public ushort GetDataUshort(byte startingDataIndex)
{
  ushort output = 0;
  for (byte i = startingDataIndex; i < this.Data.Length && i < sizeof(ushort); i++)
  {
    output |= (ushort)(this.Data[i] << (i * 8));
  }
  return output;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get data (uint)
/// </summary>
public uint GetDataUint(byte startingDataIndex)
{
  uint output = 0;
  for (byte i = startingDataIndex; i < this.Data.Length && i < sizeof(uint); i++)
  {
    output |= ((uint)this.Data[i] << (i * 8));
  }
  return output;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get data (ulong)
/// </summary>
public ulong GetDataUlong(byte startingDataIndex)
{
  ulong output = 0;
  for (byte i = startingDataIndex; i < this.Data.Length && i < sizeof(ulong); i++)
  {
    output |= ((ulong)this.Data[i] << (i * 8));
  }
  return output;
}
```

Could this be combined into one function, and how would I go about doing that? Like

```
SomeEnum member = (SomeEnum)GetData<ulong>(dataIndex);
```

but

```
GetData<byte>(0);

public T GetData<T>(byte startingDataIndex) // T would be byte during runtime
{
    return this.Data[dataIndex]; // Compiler: Er, T? Byte? what?
}
```

or

```
/// <summary>
/// Get data (T)
/// </summary>
public T GetData<T>(byte startingDataIndex)
{
  T output = 0; // Compiler: derp, this isn't an integer.
  for (byte i = startingDataIndex; i < this.Data.Length && i < System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)); i++)
  {
    output |= (T)(this.Data[i] << (i * 8)); // Compiler: nor is this!
  }
  return output;
}
```

Or am I really better off leaving as separate functions and maintaining them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you are going to end up having to write a function for each type that you want to deserialize.  This stems from the fact that you can't really use logic operators (&,|,etc.) or math operators (=,-,*,etc) on T.  Furthermore, there is no constraint for 'numeric' types on T so you'll get no help from that.

If you take a look into the [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you will see that even Microsoft ended up writing a bunch of different functions to read the different data types from a stream of bytes.

On the other hand, you could write some kind of generic function that would essentially route to the correct function, and return the results that way.  While it would be more convenient there would be a performance penalty, but that can be acceptable depending on your overall design approach.  For example:

```
public T ReadData<T>(int startIndex)
{
  Type t = typeof(T);

  if (t == typeof(int))
  {
    return (T)(object)ReadInt(startIndex);
  }
  else if(t == typeof(byte))
  {
    return (T)(object)ReadByte(startIndex);
  }
  else
  {
    string err = string.Format("Please support the type {0}", t);
    throw new NotSupportedException(err);
  }
}
```

Again, this is not 100% ideal, but it will work.  I have used a similar approach, and I found that after adding a few types here and there, I had support for all of the intrinsic types before I knew it.

Comment: I love that design approach, but it wouldn't compile as `ReadInt(startIndex);` would return an int (not T) and `ReadByte(startIndex);` would return a byte (not T). You can't cast to T either because the compiler wouldn't know how to convert int or byte to T.

Comment: yeah, sorry bout that, I'll update the code.  I just blasted something off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Which should be able to handle the converting to the appropriate type or a byte array. If you need to convert them to an Enum, you'll need to use `Enum.ToObject`. Unfortunately, generics are not templates and aren't really designed for this scenario. Generics are for scenario where the object your handling doesn't matter, or conforms to a particular interface. For things like this where the CLR has no general descriptor, you need to specialize and create different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Marshall.Sizeof() instead of sizeof() to be able to calculate the size of a generic type. Otherwise it's straight forward.

```
    public static T GetData<T>(byte startingDataIndex)
    {
        var length = Marshal.SizeOf(default(T));
        ulong buffer = 0;
        for (var i = startingDataIndex; i < Data.Length && i < length; i++)
        {
            buffer |= (Data[i] << (i * 8));
        }
        return (T)(object)buffer;
    }
```

notice that the |= operator cant be used on the generic type so it needs to be stored in an ulong buffer which we have to assume can hold enough bytes.

Comment: If it's so trivial, why don't you post your answer.

Comment: I fail to see the "straight forward" aspect. :\
I've updated my question.

Comment: point taken. new and improved, now also with straight forward code :) I second Nafals point about the boxing/unboxing performance hit, and would probably prefer to go for the original implementation. At least while the number of possible types are limited.

Comment: This code won't compile, and it will crash at runtime, even if T is ulong.  What if T is a double or other floating point type?

Comment: Just to say this answer works too, thanks! I don't want a long buffer where I can help it though -- a couple is extra ops on if/else conditions is slightly better than the scratch needed :)

Comment: No, not as written. I removed static and casted the ulong. Thanks for the point about the float/double though -- that didn't cross my mind as I'm not storing them yet (but may do in the future).